# Digital Signal Processing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm new in field of DSP I 'm gonna plot frequency time graph of a chirp signal, I've written code for it now problem is that program works well for some values of chirp rate but when I increase chirp rate(I'm applying linear chirp at input) it shows nonsense results, like if I change chirp rate from 500 to 3000 it may show negative slope line or constant slope line, Apparently there is no logical error in program, can somebody explain reason of it?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Also, show some code.. It might help :)

Answer (score 0):

If your chirp signal has high frequencies, you must have a fine time step to represent it. Try to make your time vector bigger with a small step. Remember that fft (what is probably what you are using) is a discrete operation.